# Split file in half to two new text files (command line/batch file)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I generated a text file with certificate info and am trying to split it in half so that the first half of the text will be saved to a key file as well as the other half to a certificate file. I was able to use

```
more +7 cert.txt > cert.crt
```

to save the bottom half to a new certificate file but am struggling on how to get the first half into a new key file.

This is being done via a batch script that is sent to and executed on a Windows machine remotely so it needs to be done just with the built in commands from Windows.

Example:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
sample key data
sample key data
sample key data
sample key data
sample key data
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
sample cert data
sample cert data
sample cert data
sample cert data
sample cert data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findstr /N` to precede every line read from the file `cert.txt` with its line number and a colon and a `for /F` loop to iterate through these augmented lines. You can then redirect every single line (with the prefix removed) into the respective output file depending on the current line number:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FULLFILE=cert.txt" & rem // (combined input file)
set "KEY_FILE=cert.key" & rem // (output key file)
set "CERTFILE=cert.crt" & rem // (output certificate file)
set "KEYLINES=7" & rem // (number of lines that belong to key file)
set "CERTLINE="  & rem // (first line of text belonging to cert. file)

if not defined KEYLINES set /A "KEYLINES=(1<<31)-1"
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
    findstr /N /R "^" "%FULLFILE%" ^& ^
        ^> "%KEY_FILE%" break ^& ^
        ^> "%CERTFILE%" break
') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    set /A "LNUM=LINE"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if defined CERTLINE (
        if "!LINE:*:=!"=="!CERTLINE!" (
            endlocal
            set /A "KEYLINES=0"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    )
    if !LNUM! LEQ !KEYLINES! (
        >> "!KEY_FILE!" echo(!LINE:*:=!
    ) else (
        >> "!CERTFILE!" echo(!LINE:*:=!
    )
    endlocal
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

You can configure this script in two ways:

1. Set `KEYLINES` to the number of lines (`7`) that belong to the key file, so that number of lines is output to the key file and all further lines are output to the certificate file; `CERTLINE` should be empty in this case.
2. Set `CERTLINE` to the first line that belongs to the certificate file (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`), so the lines are output to the key file until a line matches that string, in which case this line and all further ones are output to the certificate file; `KEYLINES` should be empty then.

Comment: Awesome! This should help immensely thank you! Quick note, when setting the input and output files, they are currently located on the D: drive so should they be appended to include the full file location? Also, when I execute the batch file, it does indeed create a key file but the online thing inside is `LINE:*:` and not the actually text. Am I invoking it wrong?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, just provide the full path (e. g., `set "FULLFILE=D:\Data\cert.txt"`). I cannot reproduce the `LINE:*:` thing (with the sample file of your question); a typo maybe? or do the true file paths/names contain `!` characters?

Comment: Okay cool, thats what I figured but just wanted to be sure. I had implemented the script before your initial comment so its no longer outputting `LINE:*:`, however now it is just outputting `\cert.txt" &             > "D:\cert.key" break &            > "D:\cert.crt" break` Another syntax issue perhaps?

Comment: There was the `usebackq` option in the `for /F` option string initially, which must not be there, so I removed it by an immediate edit; you should copy it once again (finally now, I hope ;-)) as I just fixed an issue with `!` appearing in the output file paths/names...